# Definition of Algebraically Independent Numbers

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, field-theory, extension-field

Let $x_1,\dots,x_n$ be complex numbers. Some authors define $x_1,\dots,x_n$ to be **algebraically independent numbers** if $x_1,\dots,x_n$ are algebraically independent over the field $\mathbb{Q}$ of rational numbers, while others call them **algebraically independent numbers** if they are algebraically independent over the field $\bar{\mathbb{Q}}$ of algebraic numbers.

I am pretty sure that the two definitions are equivalent, but I have a very elementary knowledge of algebra, so I cannot prove this equivalence, nor I could find some book which includes this statement.
Could someone help me by providing me a proof or some reference?
Thank you very very ... much for your help in advance.

Comment: Assume there is a nonzero polynomial $P$ with algebraic coefficients such that $P(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$. There exists a finite Galois extension $K/\mathbb{Q}$ with group $G$ containing all the coefficients of $P$. Then $Q:=\prod_{\sigma \in G}{\sigma(P)}$ is a rational nonzero polynomial and $Q(x_1,\ldots,x_n)=0$.

Comment: Dear Mindlack, thank you very very much for having kindly replied to my question! Could you write your comment as an answer, please? Thank you very very much again!

Comment: You’re welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a retelling of my comment.

Assume there is a nonzero polynomial $P$ with algebraic coefficients such that $P(x_1,\ldots,x_n)=0$.

There exists a finite Galois extension $K/\mathbb{Q}$ (with group $G$) containing all the coefficients of $P$.

Consider the nonzero polynomial $Q=\prod_{\sigma \in G}{\sigma(P)}$. It has coefficients in $K$ and is invariant under $G$ so has rational coefficients. Moreover, it’s clear $Q(x_1,\ldots,x_n)=0$.

Comment: Dear @Mindlack, thank you very very ... much for having kindly written your answer! I must admit that I am now beginning to study the theory of fields and Galois theory, so I cannot fully understand you proof, but I hope that in some weeks I will have all the notions needed to grasp it. Thank you very muc again!

Comment: I also found the following argument in the book by Murty and Rath [Transcendental Numbers](https://books.google.it/books?id=-4jkAwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=murty+rath+transcendental+numbers&hl=it&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiWwsOyybjrAhUwtYsKHan5DfYQ6AEwAHoECAQQAg#v=onepage&q=murty%20rath%20transcendental%20numbers&f=false). Let $K$ be a field, and $F$ an extension of $K$. Then the transcendence degree of $F$ over $K$ is the cardinality of a maximally algebraically independent subset of $F$ over $K$.

Comment: (continuation of the previous comment) Since the transcendence degree over $K$ or over any of the algebraic extensions of $K$ is the same, the notion of algebraic independence of complex number over $\mathbb{Q}$ or $\bar{\mathbb{Q}}$ is the same.

Comment: I know too little about the theory of fields to understand this argument. What do you think about it? Is it a straightforward one or does it involve some implicit steps?

Comment: There may be a way to do away with some of it, but I think there are implicit steps. Just the biggest one – why, with your definition, is the transcendance degree invariant when you replace the base field with an algebraic extension?

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I was thinking about! Thank you very much again for your invaluable help!